# PHP preg_match_all reoccuring pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to grab a match of open tags. Having an issue where a parent tag is opened including a child tag. The parent tag is captured but it ignores the children tags.

ex.

```
</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p><img

preg_match_all('/<(\/?[a-z]+)[^>]*\/?>/i', $trimmed_text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

would give the following output:

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 


                [1] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => /p
                [1] => 1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 

[1] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => p [1] => 6 ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>

                [1] => 19
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => /p
                [1] => 20
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 

 [1] => 24 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => p [1] => 25 ) ) )
```

Is it possible for any opened tags in a parent to have a subset array?

Comment: And here's exactly why you don't parse HTML/XML with a regex. Use DOM instead of find what you want.

Comment: I refer you to http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing it the hard way, use **[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)** to parse html,

ex:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.scroogle.org/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```